# R studio - stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a data frame that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFlWs.png):

```
  Name        F        R        L         M
1    1 564.4745 3.267577 3.056806  878.4101
2    2 593.6801 4.848597 2.507691 1450.8099
3    3 117.3233 6.819547 2.673681 1151.8267
4  Avg 776.4827 4.878574 2.746059 1160.6822
```

And I want a stacked bar chart of all variables (F,R,L,M) for each observation (1,2,3,avg) but so far I can only set up individual bars in one chart. Help, please

```
ggplot(Test.tibble, aes(x = Name, y = F, fill = Name)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
xlab("Name") +
ylab("Total") +
guides(fill = FALSE) +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: You also want your data to be in the long format.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Name, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Name, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Obviously the magnitude of `R` and `L` are much smaller than `F` and `M`, so they are very hard to see.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `barplot`

```
barplot(`colnames<-`(t(df1[-1]), df1[[1]]), legend = TRUE, 
      col = c('blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("1", "2", "3", "Avg"), F = c(564.4745, 
593.6801, 117.3233, 776.4827), R = c(3.267577, 4.848597, 6.819547, 
4.878574), L = c(3.056806, 2.507691, 2.673681, 2.746059), M = c(878.4101, 
1450.8099, 1151.8267, 1160.6822)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```